# F# postfix keywords for type

Tags: f#

To my knowledge, there's a special notation for the Option and List type in F#. For example, `Option<'a>` it's the same as writing `'a option`, and so it is for `'a list` and `FSharpList<'a>`.

Are these specific language keywords, or there is a way to define custom types that could use the "post-fix" notation the same way `list` and `option` do?

Comment: I have seen that there are recommendations as to which syntax to use for various circumstances. Not sure where I've seen it, but maybe one place is the site _F# for fun and profit_.

Comment: this is just two ways to define the type, the original from OCAML, and the .NET way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this for any F# type you want to define. You don't get automatic lowercase versions of your names... but then, neither do the F# built-in types: in `FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs` in the F# source code, there's a definition `type 'a list = List<'a>`, which is why you can write `int list` rather than `List<int>`.

And you can use either `Foo<'a>` or `'a Foo` (or `'a foo`) when you define your type, too. The only rule is that you must match the casing style you used when defining the type. Here's an F# Interactive session to demonstrate:

```
> type Foo<'a> = 'a list ;;
type Foo<'a> = 'a list

> type 'a bar = 'a list ;;
type 'a bar = 'a list

> let x : int Foo = [] ;;
val x : Foo<int> = []

> let y : Foo<int> = [] ;;
val y : Foo<int> = []

> let z : int bar = [] ;;
val z : int bar = []

> let w : bar<int> = [] ;;
val w : int bar = []
```

But you must match the casing of the type you defined:

```
> let x : int foo = [] ;;

  let x : int foo = [] ;;
  ------------^^^

error FS0039: The type 'foo' is not defined. Maybe you want one of the following:
   Foo
   Foo`1

> let y : Bar<int> = [] ;;

  let y : Bar<int> = [] ;;
  --------^^^

error FS0039: The type 'Bar' is not defined. Maybe you want one of the following:
   bar
   bar`1
```

Note that we got `Foo<int>` as the type listed in F# Interactive responses whether we defined our type as `int Foo` or `Foo<int>`. This is not based on the case (upper or lower) we used to define the type, but rather on the prefix/postfix order we used:

```
> type foo<'a> = 'a list ;;
type foo<'a> = 'a list

> type 'a bar = 'a list ;;
type 'a bar = 'a list

> let x : 'a foo = [] ;;
val x : foo<'a>

> let y : 'a bar = [] ;;
val y : 'a bar
```

So there you go. You can use this syntax for your own types without doing anything special. The only rule is that the type must take exactly *one* generic parameter: you can't do `type d = int,string Dictionary`. For types that take two or more generic parameters, you must define them with the `Dictionary<int,string>` style.